# How to evenly space unordered listed items vertically to the browser window

Tags: html, css

I have a side menu bar that will have a different number of listed items depending on which page is displayed. How can I evenly space the listed items vertically to the browser's window using?

Comment: you should show us what you tried before (a jsfiddle or codepen for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your browser support spec, you can use `display: flex` on the container. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qouxqamu/)

Here is a reference about flexbox ([A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Comment: In your example the listed items are adjusting to 'height: 700px; in the 'ul' not the browser height.

Comment: Just make the div height 100vh and the ul height 100%